# UITableViewCell ShouldIndentWhenEditing Issues

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, indentation

Im having issues the editing mode of the tableview. When we set the table to edit mode it indents the row cells to the right for edit field on the right. I want to stop this from happening. I have set the cell.shouldIndentWhileEditing = NO; but this doesn't change anything.

Another thing to note is this cell is programmatically built on the fly e.g.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListingCustomCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 34) reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    cell.shouldIndentWhileEditing = NO;

//SETUP CELL FIELDS

//return cell;
```

Any ideas on what im doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your UITableViewDelegate is returning YES in `- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. If the delegate method is implemented, it'll override the value on the cell.

Comment: That method was not implemented. I implemented it and returned NO but it still did not make a difference??

Answer (score 0):

Did you read this part of the documentation?

> This property has an effect only on table views created in the grouped
>   style (`UITableViewStyleGrouped`); it has no effect on
>   `UITableViewStylePlain` table views.

Maybe that’s your case.